# Confusión al pasar a mayúsculas palabras de una frase en Java

Tags: java, array, string, arraylist

Estoy intentando resolver este ejercicio **-el enunciado está a continuación-**.
Sólo consulto si el camino que tomé fue más complicado, osea ¿habrá alguna otra manera de resolverlo, que sea más simple? El **error especifico** en este código es cuando intento agregar caracter por caracter (*con charAt()*) el string que se ingresó por consola:

*Descripción: En varios procesadores de texto tiene la función “Cambiar minúsculas y mayúsculas". Tu tarea es programar parte de esa función,
pasar a mayúsculas.

Entrada: Una sola línea de a lo más 255 caracteres. Los caracteres solamente serán letras del alfabeto inglés, números y espacios.

Salida: Una sola línea, con la cadena dada en la entrada, trasformada a mayúsculas.

Ejemplo e/s:

cupa 2012
CUPA 2012*

````
import static java.io.FileDescriptor.in;
import static java.lang.System.in;
import java.util.*;
import static javax.management.Query.in;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        String entrada = input.nextLine(); //leemos de consola
        ArrayList<String> v=new ArrayList<String>(); //lo dejamos declarado nomas
        for(int a=0;a<entrada.length();a++){
            v.add(entrada.charAt(a));
        }

        char[] v_entrada=entrada.toCharArray(); 
        for (int i = 0; i <entrada.length(); i++){
            if(v_entrada[i]>='a' && v_entrada[i]<='z'){
                Character.toUpperCase(v_entrada[i]);
            }
        }
        for(char x:v_entrada){
            System.out.print(x);
        }   
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Te he quitado el Array porque no veo sentido coger la palabra `"Edu"` y descomponerla en `E d u` para volver a agregarla al array en char. (No haces nada con ello).

Al fin y al cabo, tienes que comprobar todo el texto y mostrarlo en mayúsculas, no letra por letra.

Además, faltarían las comprobaciones.

Por último un pequeño detalle (Manía mía), si recoges un texto "Edu" y lo almacenas en una variable o array en mayúsculas (EDU), **has pérdido el texto original**(que podría ser usado en un futuro).

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        do{
          boolean correct = true; // Variable para comprobar.
          String entrada = input.nextLine(); // Leemos de consola.
          // Hacemos las comprobaciones

          if(entrada.lenght > 255){  //Con esto compruebas la longitud de la String.
            System.out.print("La frase tiene más de 255 caracteres.");
            correct = false;
          }

          // Para las cadenas se usa una expresión regular, es decir, si el texto no contiene lo de la expresión, es un texto válido.

          if(!Pattern.matches(entrada, "[a-zA-Z0-9-]+"){ Una o más letras, mayúsculas, minúsculas, dígitos o el guión."
            System.out.print("La cadena no cumple el patrón.");
            correct = false;
          }
          // Para este caso, se comprueba que `entrada` sólo puede tener carácteres en minúsculas "a-z", carácteres en mayúsculas "A-Z", que puede contener dígitos entre el "0-9" y puede contener guiones, 
          // En el if, he puesto !Pattern, significa, que sino cumple la condición, no es válido.

          // Para las expresiones regulares puedes consultar y hacer la que necesites:
          // http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Expresiones_Regulares_en_Java
          // https://programacion.net/articulo/expresiones_regulares_en_java_127

        }while(!correct); // No saldrá del bucle hasta que el contenido sea válido.

        // Imprimimos el contenido en mayúsculas
        System.out.print(entrada.toUpperCase());

    }
```

Comment: Lo pasé a un array para luego transformar a este en uno de tipo char y asi poder jugar con los caracteres `if(v_entrada[i]>='a' && v_entrada[i]<='z')` asi no tenia que llenar un vector con todas las letras del abecedario y compararlas.
Sobre tu manía no logro entenderla xd, al fin y al cabo cada caracter queda asociado a un indice el cual no ha cambiado, sigue haciendo referencia al mismo caracter solo que de distinto tipo, pero eso queda entre nosotros , no? Por ultimo, mi mania es no usar expresiones regulares sino ingeniármelas para hacer lo mismo pero con mi codigo. 
PD: Gracias